# Issue when trying to read files from a sharepoint/network location in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have an issue when trying to access files from a document library on sharepoint using c#. When I open the sharepoint document library in internet explorer the url is on the format "http://intranet.com/Projects/site/Forms/AllItems.aspx". If I open the library using explorer from the sharepoint page an explorer window opens up and the adress line shows "http://intranet.com/Projects/site" and if I look at the properties I see the location "\\intranet.com\DavWWWRoot\Projects\site".

So, in my application i want to put all csv files in the library in a string using the following code:

```
string storedpath = "\\\\intranet.com\\DavWWWRoot\\Projects\\site\\";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(storedpath, "*.csv")
           .Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path))
           .ToArray();
```

And this works fine now, but when I try after a restart I will get an error message that the path cannot be found. However, if I manually open explorer and paste "\\intranet.com\DavWWWRoot\Projects\site" in the adress bar I can access it. And after I have opened it manually, my application is able to find it again..

One solution may be to add the following code to open the folder in explorer prior to reading the files:

```
var pro = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
pro = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("\\\\intranet.com\\DavWWWRoot\\Projects\\site\\");
```

But I can`t figure out how to close this window. Is there a way to close this window? Or a way to perform this in the background?

Comment: Have you tried to map your intranet location to a local network drive and see if it works without starting a new process?

Comment: I will try tomorrow morning if it`s not accessible anymore. To map the network drive and disconnect it when I`m done may be a solution. But it seems like this will cause a wait time because I need to add a Thread.Sleep(1000) to wait for the drive to be mapped before i try to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to call the NET command instead of opening an explorer window. This should connect the network share without leaving any windows open:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\windows\system32\net.exe", @"use \\intranet.com\DavWWWRoot\Projects\site");
```

Note that you can save yourself the double-backslashes by using the @ prefix for strings. It may be helpful to get familiar with the NET command on windows, which gives you lots of options when connecting network shares.